# How to select only date part in postgres by using django ORM

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-orm

My backend setting as following

- Postgres 9.5
- Python 2.7
- Django 1.9

I have a table with datetime type, which named `createdAt`. I want to use Django ORM to select this field with only date part and group by `createdAt` filed.

For example, this `createdAt` filed may store `2016-12-10 00:00:00+0`、`2016-12-11 10:10:05+0`、`2016-12-11 17:10:05+0` ... etc。

By using Djanggo ORM, the output should be `2016-12-10`、`2016-12-11`。The corresponding sql should similar to: `SELECT date(createdAt) FROM TABLE GROUP BY createdAt`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use a group function by date (such as count(*)) or just using that as an example? You could use a template filter if you just need to display it, or if using it frequently, perhaps create a model property.

Answer (score 2):

You can try that:

1. use `__date` operator to Filter by `DateTimeField` with date part: `createAt__date`, this is similar to `__lt` or `__gt`.
2. use [**annotate**/**Func**/**F**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to create an extra field base on `createAt` with only showing the date part.
3. use `values` and `annotate`, `Count`/`Sum` to create `group by` query.

#### Example code

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Func, F, Count

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)
    createAt = models.DateTimeField('create at', auto_now=True)

Post.objects.filter(createAt__date='2016-12-26')    # filter the date time field for specify date part                         
            .annotate(createAtDate=Func(F('createAt'), function='date'))  # create an extra field, named createAtDate to hold the date part of the createAt field, this is similar to sql statement: date(createAt) 
            .values('createAtDate')  # group by createAtDate                                     
            .annotate(count=Count('id')) # aggregate function, like count(id) in sql statement
```

#### output

```
[{'count': 2, 'createAtDate': datetime.date(2016, 12, 26)}]
```

#### Notice:

1. To specify each method's functionality, I have break the long statement into serval pieces, so you need to remove the carriage return when you paste it to your code.
2. When you have turned on timezone in your application, like `USE_TZ = True`, you need be more carefully when compare two dates in django. Timezone is matter when you making query as above.

Hope it would help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Django provide `Manager.raw()` to perform raw queries on model but as raw query must contains primary key that is not useful in your case. In case `Manager.raw()` is not quite enough you might need to perform queries that don’t map cleanly to models, you can always access the database directly, routing around the model layer entirely by using `connection`. `connection` object represent the default database connection. So you can perform you query like.

```
from django.db import connection
#acquire cursor object by calling connection.cursor()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT created_at from TABLE_NAME GROUP BY created_at')
```

After executing query you can iterate over cursor object to get query result.